# switch() and changing the variable

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have a switch statement, which deals with the variable `$action`, and then loads the data accordingly.  However, let us say that a particular action is not possible, and has been determined in the middle of a switch, for instance:

```
switch($action)
{
    case "view":
     if($id) { 
            // perform actions
        } else {
            $action = false;
        }
    break;
    case "false":
        // perform other actions
    break;
}
```

The problem is that It appears that I cannot do that.  Once a switch statement has been set in  motion, the variable appears to be locked into that instance.

Is there way around this?

Comment: How about another local variable in the `else` part which will be re-assigned to `$action` at the end of `switch`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use some form of recursion with the switch being wrapped in a function, depending on actually what you need inside the switch statement and what you are doing.

For example:

```
function myFunction($action){
    switch($action)
    {
    case "view": 
        if($id) { 
            // perform actions
        } else {
            myFunction(false);
        }
    break;
    case "false":
        // perform other actions
    break;
    }

}
```

I agree with the other answer though, this is looking like it will get out of hand. Maybe a refactoring is a better solution.

Comment: I actually quite like this.  Its kind of outside the box.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using switch case in that scenario. write some methods handling these scenarios.
e.g

```
if(isActionSucessful($action)) //checks if $action == view
   performYourActions($id);    // check if $id is ok, if not then call cleanup;
else
   performCleanupActions() ..;
```

generally fall through cases and switch are not so clear for readers - you have to put additional comment that it is indeed intentional.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice for a case (pardon the pun) like this would be to reconsider your logic.

Something like this would be much more clear.

```
switch ($action)
{
    case "view":
        do_view($id);
        break;
    case "something_else":
        //...
}

function do_view($id)
{
    if ($id)
    {
        do_action_success();
    }
    else
    {
        do_action_false();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have gone with removing the `case false:` from the `switch` and putting outside in an `if {}`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. There are workarounds for specific cases you might be able to use, for example

```
case "view":
    if ($id) {
        // perform actions
        break;
    }
    // intentional fall-through
case "false":
    // other actions
break;
```

This won't always work because you can only fall-through from a single code path to another. But you can work around this restriction by using a reversed switch statement:

```
switch(true) {
    case $action == 'view' && $id:
        break;
    case $action == 'view' && !$id:
        // intentional fall-through -- but you can now write many of these
    case $action == 'false':
        break;
}
```

That said, code like this is way too unusual to be written with impunity. When a straight `switch` seems not enough I recommend taking a step back and trying to refactor the code rather than trying to bludgeon the switch into submission.

Comment: Note that the first type of code (skipping breaks within a case) is not very maintainable and may lead to subtle bugs.

Comment: @StevenLiao: The second type is even worse. ;-)

Comment: didn't see your edit text, only your initial case. I guess we were in agreement before I started typing xD.

Comment: That is quite mad! I havent seen switches like that before.  And will the second one definitely work?? I've tried using conditional statements before in the `case:` and it's resulted in errors.

Comment: Also, I did consider fall throughs but I don't like their unpredictability; and they would not work if there was a need for more than one fall through.

Comment: @Chud37: I don't like code like this either. Refactor what you have instead -- go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com and post the whole function.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
$action = "view";
$id = false;
callswitch($action,$id);
function callswitch($action,$id){
switch($action)
{
    case "view":
        if($id) { 
            echo 'inside case view';    
            break;
        } else {
            callfunc();                 
            break;
        }       
    case "false":
        echo 'inside case false';
    break;
}
}

function callfunc(){
    $action = "false";
    $id = true;
    callswitch($action,$id);
}
```